# Sorting two plotly bar charts by column value

Tags: python, plotly

Let's suppose this is my dataset:

```
my_data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
  'Countries':['Australia', 'Canada', 'China', 'Netherlands'],
  'A':[1.89,1.45,1.22,0.94],
  'B':[0.8,1,1.45,1.6]
})
```

I have this two bar plots:
[image]

I want to order the countries by the value of 'A' in both plots, but I tried a lot of things and just can't. I will be very grateful for any help.

This is my code:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar( 
      x=my_data['A'], 
      y=my_data['Countries'], 
      orientation='h', 
      text = my_data['A'], 
      name = 'A'),
    row=1, col=1
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar( 
      x=my_data['B'], 
      y=my_data['Countries'], 
      orientation='h', 
      text = my_data['B'], 
      name = 'B'),
    row=1, col=2
)

fig.update_layout(barmode='stack', yaxis={'categoryorder':'total ascending'})
fig.update_layout(height=600, width=1000, title_text="Side By Side Subplots")
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a more plotly-specific way to do this, but you can use `fig.update_yaxes(categoryorder='array', categoryarray=desired_order)` to update all the subplot y axes, where `desired_order` is a list to use for ordering. So if you want to order by column `A`, `desired_order = my_data.sort_values('A')['Countries'].to_list()`. All together:

```py
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

my_data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
  'Countries':['Australia', 'Canada', 'China', 'Netherlands'],
  'A':[1.89,1.45,1.22,0.94],
  'B':[0.8,1,1.45,1.6]
})

desired_order = my_data.sort_values('A')['Countries'].to_list()
print(desired_order)

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar( 
      x=my_data['A'], 
      y=my_data['Countries'], 
      orientation='h', 
      text = my_data['A'], 
      name = 'A'),
    row=1, col=1
)



fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar( 
      x=my_data['B'], 
      y=my_data['Countries'], 
      orientation='h', 
      text = my_data['B'], 
      name = 'B'),
    row=1, col=2
)


fig.update_yaxes(categoryorder='array', categoryarray=desired_order)
fig.update_layout(barmode='stack')
fig.update_layout(height=600, width=1000, title_text="Side By Side Subplots")
fig.show()
```

produces

[image: plot bar subplot axis ordering]

I couldn't get the same behavior using just `update_layout`, not sure if that's a bug or a usage issue (I don't know plotly super well).

Edit: I figured out how to use update_layout. As noted in this thread: https://community.plotly.com/t/fig-update-layout-only-affecting-first-subplot/29648 , `yaxis` is only the first subplot, you can specify `yaxis2` to reference the second subplot. So if you want to use `update_layout` (and not `update_yaxes`), you could do the following:

```py
fig.update_layout(barmode='stack', yaxis={'categoryorder':'array', 'categoryarray':desired_order},
                  yaxis2={'categoryorder':'array', 'categoryarray':desired_order})
```

Comment: Nice I was having the same problem whan I was using update_layout, I think they might be an error in plotly

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I'd tried using update_loyout but I didn't know about yaxis2. 
Now it's working good:)